# How to update column id order by date desc

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm working on mySQL which is the data is unsorted. So I'd like to re-sort them by date most current. And update the id column by it's order. Here is my structure.

**booking_db**

```
+----+------------+------+
| id |    date    | name |
+----+------------+------+
| 98 | 2014-10-07 |  A   |
+----+------------+------+
| 75 | 2014-12-05 |  F   |
+----+------------+------+
|120 | 2013-05-01 |  C   |
+----+------------+------+
```

As expected. I'd like my data to sort like this.

```
+----+------------+------+
| id |    date    | name |
+----+------------+------+
| 3  | 2014-12-05 |  F   |
+----+------------+------+
| 2  | 2014-10-07 |  A   |
+----+------------+------+
| 1  | 2013-05-01 |  C   |
+----+------------+------+
```

I tried delete the id column. And ideally hope to create a new one with auto-increment order by date desc. But it's not work.

Please be advice.

Comment: I'd copy the data to another temp table... drop the table and recreate it with an AUTOINC id column... reinsert the data ordered by date. Have you tried this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution.

1. export as csv
2. open it in texteditor
3. save it as ansi
4. open it in ms excel
5. sort the date column asc
6. type "1" in the first column and press ctrl+drag to the last row
7. save & close
8. open it in texteditor
9. save it as utf-8
10. import it back to mysql

Job done!
Thank you for every comments.